# Data sent back to Uitableview

Tags: uitableview, ios5

I have a `UITableviewController` and I push another `UIViewController` in 'didSelectRow..' method.

I have user input controls (combobox, stepper) in this viewController, that when the `UIViewController` is popped , I would like to receive the newly entered data in the `UITableviewController` (and update the tableview accordingly).

I saw some questions/answers, and some said to use "Delegation/Protocol" approach, but did not find any specific example how to achieve this.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file for your project and choose the Protocol file type.  (We'll call it `CallBackProtocol`.)  In the view controller that you push, create a property that has a type of `id<CallBackProtocol> delegate;`.  Have your table controller adopt the protocol and, when it creates the view controller, set `controller.delegate = self;`.

Define a method in the protocol that lets you pass whatever data you need back to the caller.  Implement that method in the table controller and call it from the second view controller just before popping it.

(Or use a `NSNotification`.)

Comment: Lets say I populate my table from an NSArray. I assume that once data is received in the tableViewController (ie, the detail view controller is popped), I have to "modify my array" and call "reloadData" on my tableView. How can I modify that array? I dont understand how I can get a reference to the correct uitableviewcell.

Comment: If your table controller turns off `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`, you should be able to get the selected cell when you return.  If there's a problem with that, then you can always save the selected row number (or index path) when a cell is selected.

Comment: Couldnot make it work with clearsSelectionOnVIewWillAppear, although seems promisinig. If someone else is interested, on viewDidDisappear of child viewcontroller, I fire this delegation method, only to be caught by the parent view controller. Plus, I keep a reference to the "row-in-action" in the parent view controller, and update everything accordingly. Thanks again :)